# How can I change my system's PS/2 mouse polling rate?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, mouse

According to my research, it should be possible to increase my PS/2 polling rate from the default 100Hz to 200Hz. However, I have not been able to find any information on how to do this for a PS/2 mouse; only for a USB mouse. Does anyone know how to configure this?

My mouse driver is named "`ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse`" and I used the tool `evhz` to determine that its current polling rate is 100Hz. I am running Arch Linux; my input drivers use `xorg.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> psmouse.rate= [HW,MOUSE] Set desired mouse report rate, in reports
>               per second.
> ```

[source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt)

Therefore, pass the desired value to the kernel in your boot options.